# How to find the growth rate for a certain year?

Tags: numerical-methods

```
 The following is the question.

 The world population growth rate at a certain reference year was 3.5%. 
 Assuming exponential growth of population, after how many years, will the 
 population of the world would have increased by a factor 16 ?
```

I do not know how to start the problem. Is it the start of problem solving with equations, or something more generic?
       Can someone give a pointer as to how to solve this problem?

Comment: $ 1.035^n = 16; n = log_{\,1.035}{16}$

Comment: how do you get the value of n?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the population keeps growing at the same rate $3.5%$, it can be modeled:
$$P(t)=P_0e^{0.035t} \Rightarrow P_0e^{0.035t}=16P_0 \Rightarrow t \approx 79.22.$$

Comment: now how to solve this? e^{0.035t}=16 without an calculator?

Comment: You cannot, because: $t=\frac{\ln 16}{0.035}\approx 79.2168206354...$

Answer (score 1):

$$ 1.035^n=16\rightarrow n=log_{1.035}\,16 $$

$n $ in the above has been arrived at from compound interest formula

$$P/P_0=(1+r)^n $$

Take logs to any base, getting $ \log 16/ \log 1.035=87.0816$ years.

The above is based on compound interest taken once every year. The exponential formula is a mathematical limit formula arrived at by assuming that compound interest is computed for every nanosecond!  So exponentiation builds to 20 times amount in a much shorter time.